# По завершению теста Jenkins выводит ошибки

Tags: java, test-automation, jenkins, testng

В чем проблема? Почему по завершению теста, Jenkins выводит следующие ошибки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у вас 6 тестов упало...

Comment: как выше сказали, это у вас тесты падают. а surefire плагин в конце выдает такой краткий результат. Проблема не в CI, а в тестах